# Accessing $_COOKIE from an included PHP file outside of webroot

Tags: php, cookies

Question is in the title.

I can access `$_COOKIE['blah']` in my php file in the webroot, but I have includes outside of webroot for security purposes that can't access it.

**Example**

`/home/wwwroot/index.php` CAN read $_COOKIE['blah']

Where it's full path would be `http://www.mydomain.com/index.php`.

`/home/scrape/process.php` CAN *NOT* read $_COOKIE['blah']

But it is outside the webroot, and the `scrape` folder can't be access outside of the server.

**Index.php** can echo the value stored in the cookie and will also write a timestamp with the value to a log file.  This works.

Without posting ALL the code and trying to keep this simple and it's just something simple like so:

```
<?PHP
include '../scrape/process.php'; // THIS FILE IS OUTSIDE THE WEBROOT
$cook=$_COOKIE['blah'];

echo "Cookie value is : " . $_COOKIE['blah'] ;
error_log('['.date("F j, Y, g:i a e O").']'.$cook."<br /> \n", 3,  $phperrorPath);
?>

<?PHP
echo 'Outer cookie is : ';
echo outer_cookie();
?>
```

**Process.php** function is called from index.php where it will then return the value of the cookie, and also write it's own log file with timestamp and cookie value.  This does not work.  The log file has only timestamp with no value, and it doesn't return anything to index.php.

```
function outer_cookie() 
{ 
    $cook=$_COOKIE['blah'];
    error_log('['.date("F j, Y, g:i a e O").']'.$cook."<br /> \n", 3,  $phperrorPath);
    return $cook; 
}
```

How can I get process.php to read the cookie data?  I obviously can't set the cookie path to something outside of the webroot, and even if I could, then it wouldn't be accessible to everything in the webroot...

Do I have to use `$_SESSION` along side the cookie?  I would hate to have to duplicate the work...

Comment: The cookie is based on the domain where is set - if you set a cookie in `example.com` it will be available in `test.example.com` and `test2.example.com, How it's your structure?

Comment: How are you testing this exactly? It doesn't matter where the file is in the file system for it to access cookies.

Comment: @MihaiIorga Right, I understand that, but the process.php file is not in the web root of the domain, so how can it be seen at being part of mydomain.com when it can only be access by the server and not by client?

Comment: @deceze my index.php can echo the value of the cookie and write it to a log.  The process.php is set to return the value of the cookie to index.php from a GET and also write it to a log.  Process.php returns null and writes nothing to the log, just a timestamp with nothing beside it.

Comment: Show your code. How is the code in that file executed, what exactly is the code?

Comment: *"Process.php is called with a GET from index.php"* - What does that mean?

Comment: @deceze Sorry my bad, I'm extremely tired from long shifts... index.php calls a function in the included process.php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do make this work both file should be in your domain or subdomains of one domain.

You cannot access the cookie set in `index.php` in a file that does not have web access and it's not parsed by the browser.

Check [php.net](https://www.php.net/manual/en/features.cookies.php):

*Cookies are a mechanism for storing data in the remote browser and thus tracking or identifying return users. Cookies are part of the HTTP header, so setcookie() must be called before any output is sent to the browser.*

Comment: So even if this included php file tries to process the cookie information before anything else happens, it won't ever be able to read the cookie data?

Comment: It can read the data if the file is included in your scripts that are processed and sent to the browser. So if you include `/home/scrape/process.php` in your `index.php` it will access any cookie you set.

Comment: That's what I figure *should* happen, but it's not for some reason.  If I move process.php to the webroot (same folder as index.php) and change the index's include to `'process.php';`, then it works fine...  But when it's outside the webroot, it doesn't work.

Comment: then you have a problem, a problem that it's not cookie related as the steps you mention are ok ... maybe with your `error_log()`, maybe `$phperrorPath` it's not a valid path ..

Comment: $phperrorpath was just typed in here because I didn't want to type out my paths here.  What else could it be then?

Comment: Try to simplify things. Create index2.php and process2.php and add this to see what brakes your code or unsets your cookies

Comment: I'll try that.  And the cookies are not being unset because index can still read them, but process can't when it's outside the webroot.  I'll get back to you.